# SVG as CSS background, problems with zoom level in Opera

Tags: css, svg, background, opera

I'm having difficulties using SVG background with Opera.

When I zoom out the page, the background starts repeating on the x axis despite `background-repeat: repeat-y'

I created a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/werLp) showing off the problem with the first online SVG image I found.

```
body {
  background-image: url("http://www.anarchopedia.org/images/2/22/Heckert_GNU_white.svg");
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

And here is a screenshot of Opera's 12.14 behavior on my computer:

[image: Opera starts repeating the background on the x axis when zooming out]

The behavior exhibits for any SVG document with `width="W" height="H" viewBox="0 0 W H"` dimensioning.

I tried various values for `width`, `height`, `viewBox` and even `preserveAspectRatio` on the root `<svg>` element without much success so far.

Any hint please?

Comment: Known issue (CORE-33071). Not sure if there's a simple workaround, using <img>, <object>, <iframe> or plain inline svg instead of background-image is one way.

Comment: I'm fine with a browser hack that reverts to PNG background actually. If suck a "trigger only Opera" hack exists though

Comment: actually, removing the `viewBox` solves half of the problem: zoon in works, zoom out still broken. Too bad the CORE-33071 bug report isn't public

Answer (score 1):

Its not simple as Opera does not redraw the Image after Resize,

refer this [link](https://github.com/dpvc/MathJax/commit/27d3b1ea80d52d8809427ab757ac40b5f8b2b1eb)

this link explains how to force opera to redraw the image after zoom,

I have tried the easy way but not working,

so I think this is the only way to deal with opera bug. Seems it is using MathJax framework,

I hope this may help..